# onmouseout not working

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseout

I have a little problem. I am calling a function on `onmouseout` event of the event, it works fine but it is not changing the `innerHTML`. Below is my function:

```
function rvrtImg(id) {
  alert(id);
  if(id=="img1") {
    alert(id)
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "<img src='<?php echo     
        get_bloginfo('template_directory')?>/img/paging/1.png' />"; 
  }
}
```

Here, I am calling it

```
<a href="#"  id="img1" onmouseover="repImg(this.id)" onmouseout="rvrtImg(this.id)">hello</a>
```

Only alert is working but its not changing the inner HTML

Comment: Can you reproduce this, at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? And why not pass the node itself to the function, rather than the `id` and then looking for the element with `getElementById(id)`?

Comment: What is the the browser output WITHOUT your PHP code?

Comment: @DavidThomas [link]http://jsfiddle.net/Z9jgv/ is my code

Comment: @Baig can you tell us *which* alert is working? Only the first one, or both?

Comment: @Diodeus well without PHP code, as you can see, my other function `repImg()` is working

Comment: @thaJeztah both are working

Comment: [But it works](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Z9jgv/1/) (despite the `Uncaught ReferenceError: repImg is not defined`).

Comment: @Baig have you tried alerting the result of the PHP code, like this: alert("<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory')?>");

Comment: For all we know, the value of <?php echo      get_bloginfo('template_directory')?> could be corrupting your function, but we can't even tell.

Comment: first of all, insert this php function on a html tag just to see the result, if everything is fine try concatenating the template_directory inside the php.

Comment: well now `onmouseout` is not working

Comment: well now `onmouseout` is not working

Answer (score 0):

WordPress?

```
<a href="#" id="img1" class="paging image1">hello</a>
```

You can use jQuery to handle the mouseover/out:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

    $( 'a.paging.image1' ).hover(
        function() { $( this ).html( '<img src="hoverimage1.png" alt="" />' ); },
        function() { $( this ).html( '<img src="normalimage1.png" alt="" />' ); }
     );

} );

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because image is bigger than current size of anchor. This will prevent mouse out from triggering properly.

Here is a working example: (Note to CSS)
http://jsfiddle.net/QQSLC/16/

```
<a href="#" id="img1" onmouseover="repImg(this.id)" onmouseout="rvrtImg(this.id)">hello with lower size than image</a>
<a href="#" id="img2" onmouseover="repImg(this.id)" onmouseout="rvrtImg(this.id)">hello with higher size than image</a>

a {
    background: green;
}
#img2{
    background: red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 120px;
    display: block;
}
```

Just for more info:

When you have an anchor with auto size it use font height for height and autosize for width.
Lets think that in this case size of our anchor is about 100px X 23px
Now you want to load a picture at mouse out. This will change anchor height with height of picture within it so anchor become 600px X 300px. When this thing happen mouse is still in this area (cuz it was out of 23px. But now it is 300px. So mouse is still there) so browser trigger mouseover again. At same time mouse over code changed height of anchor to 23px so mouse is out again and this loop go for ever. For preventing this sort of paradoxes, browsers decided to ignore mouseout at elements with smaller size then mouse over size. (Until you do CSS or change size manually instead of automatically)

Please note than mouse out work if you move your mouse from above or left of element because any change in size of anchor has no effect on this two direction.